# SSRS Use 1st Parameter (Multi choice) or 2nd Parameter (Text) for same SQL Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, multi-select, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I would like to use 2x Report Parameters for the same SQL parameter.

Currently I have the following in my WHERE clause which relates to a multi-select drop-down:

```
 and traderid in(@traderid)
```

But I would like to have something along the lines of:

```
and (traderid in (@traderid) OR traderid = (@traderid2)
```

so that users can either type the name that they require as opposed to finding in in the vast drop-down list, or choose multiple traders from the drop-down.

In trying so far, I cannot leave the multi-select blank as SSRS will not run the report and you cannot specify the 'Allow Null option' for multi-select parameters.

Does anyone know if there is a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a value to your multiselect parameter that effectively means "Ignore this and use the text box".

For instance, add an option to the multiselect with value `-1` and label `-Enter Manually-`.

In your query, do this:

```
and (traderid in (@traderid) or (-1 in (@traderid) and traderid = @traderid2))
```

The above assumes your `traderid` is integer. If not, adjust accordingly.